# Restrict cell animation when reordering collection view

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to add an animation to my collection view cells so that they animate when the collection view is scrolled. At the moment it is working, but it interferes with a library I'm using which allows the cells to be reordered.

It's difficult to explain what's happening, but there is basically a 'ghost' cell in the position that the cell you are dragging to, has just moved from. Regardless, I need to figure out a way to detect when the cells are being reordered so that I can cancel the animation.

This is the library I'm using: https://github.com/ra1028/RAReorderableLayout

And this is the animation:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {        
    cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1,0.1,1)
    cell.alpha = 0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.35, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: {
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1,1,1)
    }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.45, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: {
        cell.alpha = 1
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions?